# SEO friendly URL is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

In my .htaccess file, a have plenty of SEO friendly links. And now I'm trying to apply SEO friendly link to a subfolder. (these files are in "latvia" folder)

Here is a content of .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE SSL_REDIRECT:SSL_REDIRECT

RewriteRule ^latvia/2017/tournaments latvia/2017-lv-calendar.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^latvia/adults/tournaments latvia/lvt_adults.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^latvia/juniors/tournaments latvia/lvt_juniors.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^latvia/federation latvia/lv-federation.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^latvia/juniors/rankings latvia/lvj-rankings.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^latvia/adults/rankings latvia/lva-rankings.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^latvia/rankings latvia/lv-rankings.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^latvia latvia/index.php [NC]
```

It works fine if to go to /latvia. But if to go to latvia/2017/tournaments (or any other page) for some reason it will give the same page as /latvia

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

add L to the rules e.g. `[NC, L]` to indicate that it's the last rewrite to happen, otherwise since everything starts with `^latvia` all rules will fall through the last rule.

Code:

```
RewriteRule ^latvia/2017/tournaments latvia/2017-lv-calendar.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^latvia/adults/tournaments latvia/lvt_adults.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^latvia/juniors/tournaments latvia/lvt_juniors.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^latvia/federation latvia/lv-federation.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^latvia/juniors/rankings latvia/lvj-rankings.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^latvia/adults/rankings latvia/lva-rankings.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^latvia/rankings latvia/lv-rankings.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^latvia latvia/index.php [NC,L]
```

You can always tests your .htaccess using pages like e.g. http://htaccess.mwl.be/